# Convert PHP Doctrine date to JS

Tags: javascript, php, doctrine

There is a webservice that provides me dates in JSON format like this:

```
startDate: {date: "2020-10-08 00:00:00.000000", timezone_type: 3, timezone: "Europe/Paris"}
```

Which would be the easiest way to convert that object into a JS Datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) with [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)